I cannot provide on-page padding in print mode
We are dynamically creating a PDF, and due to the varying length of the content, some of it overflows onto the next page. While we've managed to prevent content from overlapping with page breaks, we're struggling to maintain proper padding for the text that moves to the next page. This is becoming quite frustrating.
Using margins on @page solves the padding issue, but it creates another problem: the background colors no longer cover the full width and height, which is essential for our dense design. We need the background to completely cover the page.
enter image description here
 jsfiddle.net/sxehk7Lb 
We have attempted to set margins using the @page rule to ensure that content does not overlap with page breaks and maintains appropriate padding. However, while this approach solves the padding problem, it causes the background colors to not extend to the full width and height of the page, which is a critical requirement for our design. We expected to find a solution that maintains both the full-page background coverage and the proper padding for the content.

PDF pages are not flowable objects. Each page is a standalone object, thus contents of pages should be able to support / reflect a staggered rendering like shown in solution below. Tables and list cannot be considered as spanning pages but must be divided between pages.
This causes frequent issues when converting HTML flowable objects into PDF separate objects without wrapping or overflow.
Another problem is that printed PDF pages must be declared at their start as dimensionless /MediaBox [x1 y1 x2 y2] and for imperial those undefined units are defaulted to nominal printers points [0 0 612 792] but HTML likes to use pixels at a nominal density of 96 per screen inch.
Thus a compromise is to declare printing "Letter" page size as 816 x 1056 pixels. for metric we consider that as 793 x 1122 pixels so a problem arises when preparing for a global market and many applications fail to consider the dual requirement in full page printing without margins.
In fact a side effect of that view is that an A4 page is wrongly reported as 1.333% bigger in Edge Browser ! it is physically 210 x 297 but reported as 280 x 396 !

Thus the Media print must be one fixed size or the other.
Current code cannot work reliably as not meeting the above PDF requirements.
@page {
        size: auto;
        margin: 0;
      }

      @media print {
        body {
          -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
          margin: 0;
        }

The working order needs to be changed to
@media print {
  @page {
        size: A4;
        margin: 0;
        }
        body {
          -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
          margin: 0;
        }
}

And working content lengths must not overflow those values or else you get side overflow bleeding to blank pages.

Thus if you get it right you get correctly 2 full bleed pages.
https://jsfiddle.net/8k2p1etL/6/

